# How to handle renewal of autorenewable subscriptions (ios/android)?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

Perhaps I am simply not looking in the correct places, but I am surprised at the lack of documentation around cross-platform apps incorporating renewing subscriptions.

I have a cross-platform (iOS and Android) Ionic app with a Rails API for the back-end. I am using https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase as a wrapper around the iOS/Google store SDKs.

My question revolves around subscription renewal:

From what I gather, it is recommended that I have a daily job checking each of my subscriptions for their expiration date. If a subscription is about to expire, I can send the receipt stored in my database to either Google/Apple and check if the subscription has been renewed. If it has, I update the expiration date and keep the subscription active. If the subscription has not been renewed, I mark the subscription as inactive.

Now, what happens if a user renews a subscription? How will I know that a subscription has been renewed? And when do I check for subscription renewal? Seems like my options are:

- Every day, check every expired subscription for renewal. Problems with this: 1) as the number of users grows, so will the number of users with expired subscriptions. Eventually, this will result in checking many, many expired subscriptions every night. 2) A user will be unable to access subscription-only content between the time they renew their subscription through the app/play store and the nightly subscription-checking job is run.
- Every time a user with an expired subscription logs into the app, check to see if they have renewed their subscription. Problems with this: 1) My app uses token authentication. Therefore, users are not required to login with each use. So, if a user renews their subscription, but their token is still valid, the app will have no way of knowing that their subscription is up-to-date.

Is there another option? What am I missing here?

Comment: On iOS the app will receive an updated receipt with the new subscription details. The app should provide this updated receipt to your server when the user opens it

Comment: @Paulw11 - how do I receive this updated receipt? Do you have a link to this documentation? I also wonder if https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase supports this functionality. Also, does Android offer something similar?

Comment: It is covered in the Apple in app purchasing guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6  Apple can also POST to your server to advise you of renewals.

Comment: @Paulw11saw that -- trying to determine if I need to integrate those notifications into my app (it does add a bit of complexity, and we're on a tight schedule). Also trying to figure out Android in tandem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a combination of both options.

When a user opens your app you should send a separate request to your backend that will fetch the receipt a check if its renewed and cache the expiration date and the time it was checked. Then I would have another job run nightly that doesn't check all the expired receipts, but clears the expiration date cache if it hasn't been checked within a certain period. Then, the next time a user opens the app, the cache will be empty and and will be fetched.

I'm working on adding Android subscriptions to [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) but it won't be ready for a couple months.

Comment: Checking on app load (as opposed to login) makes sense. That could work. I also saw that both Google and Apple have notifications services that your server can subscribe to -- I'm trying to determine whether integration with those services is absolutely necessary? I don't want to add complexity if I don't have to.

Comment: It's not. The notifications give you advance notice, and might let you reduce the amount of times you check, but you don't need them. They are also non-trivial to implement so might not be worth the effort.